# restful resource's name validation

Tags: validation, rest, restlet

since i'm using something like http://mywebsite.web/{nickname}/dostuff i was wondering if there's a standard validation for the "nickname" string so that it won't contain reserved characters and stuff like that

Comment: i'm starting to think i could just use org.restlet.data.Reference encode and decode methods

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across any such functionality in Restlet, but what you could do is to get the value of *{nickname}* in your resource that is handling that URL, and validate it with a regular expression.